# What is the best solution here : past perfect or past simple

Tags: past-tense

> Could you let me know if these records were still available when I ordered them because they **had been released** a long time ago.

Just wondering if were released could fit instead of "had been released". I  don't think so because we could think that the both events happened  very close  to each other(using past perfect put the release far from the order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the past perfect here because "they were released a long time ago" implies that they were released before you gave your order. In fact, I suspect that most native speakers would actually use the simple past rather than the past perfect. Of course it is **NOT** wrong to use the past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Your version sounds awkward to me.  I would go with the simple past of

> Could you let me know if these records were still available when I ordered them because they were released a long time ago.

Comment: @Lambie Whoops.  Fixed